# Vue.js and Vuetify slot-scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm really just not sure how slot-scopes work.  Wondering if somebody could help me out with this (seemingly) pretty simple problem.

```
<v-data-table>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
```

What I'm looking to do is manually update "props" to expand this  row based on an external event.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to access this outside of the context noted above.  The `props.expanded = !props.expanded` works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can also refer to this link: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a way built in to the component. As the data table creates it's own expanded object and doesn't use a passed in prop.

You can use a *ref*. [Vue page on child component refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

This following code will set the ref on the data table to `accesshere`.

```
<v-data-table ref="accesshere" :headers="headers" :items="dataTable" 
:search="search" item-key="id">
```

Now you'll be able to access that object by using (setting this to false will close the expanded table row) `this.$refs.accesshere.expanded['nameofkey'] = false`

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/twandy/pen/ZadLLd) showing it in action.

There is an issue with the expanded object and that it isn't populated until you expand a row for the first time. So if you do something like the following. It won't see those changes (unless you force the component to update) and therefore won't expand the row right away.

```
 methods: {
   itemShow () {
     this.$refs.accesshere.expanded['2'] = true
     this.$forceUpdate() // This works, I don't know if it is recommended though
  }
 }
```

Comment: Jordan, Thanks for the reply!  I've gotten this to sort of work, but it has some odd side effects.  So, what I'm trying to do now is expand a new row after it has been added. So I tried: this.$refs.accesshere.expanded['2'] = true;  And it works IF I do this.$forceUpdate(), like you noted.  But, after that, it doesn't function normally.  I can no longer click on it to collapse it.  If I click another row it collapses normally, and the other rows all are still fully functional.  Any idea why that would be happening, and/or how to fix it?